# @livewireStyles @livewire('navigation-menu') doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

[livewirestyle doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORSiz.png)

laravel8 jetstream livewire doesn't work after i run
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views

Comment: You probably just need to clear your cache, run `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Please share relevant code.

Comment: looks to me that your blade is not parsin livewire? Are you sure you installed laravel jetstream with livewire or maybe by mistake with vue? 
If not, try again, run jetstream:install and tell to use livewire/blade
this: php artisan jetstream:install livewire
after that if not work, try to clear your cache with php artisan optimize:clear